# Phone number breakdown (International Version) java

Tags: java

Given a long integer representing a 11-digit phone number, output the country code, area code, prefix, and line number using the format +1 (800) 555-1212.

Ex: If the input is:
18005551212

the output is:

+1 (800) 555-1212

So far,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      long phoneNumber;
      int countryCode, area_Code, prefix, line_Number;

      phoneNumber = scnr.nextLong();

      /* Type your code here. */
      line_Number = (int)(phoneNumber%10000);
      countryCode = (int)(phoneNumber%100/10);
      area_Code = (int)(phoneNumber/10000/1000);



      System.out.println("(" + area_Code + ") ");
}
```

I am running program just to see how I want to go about for the rest.

I have a question. After running, how can I remove the 1 in and for the area_Code?

It appears like this (1800), I want to place the 1 outside the parentheses.

Any help please, kind of newbie still.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to do this from scratch... but if not, this library will help quite a bit: https://github.com/google/libphonenumber

Comment: Following chapters from my Java book, a lot of fancy formats. Not quite there yet, but beneficial nonetheless, thanks! What I am using to code is like an online IDE , so only reason I didn’t include a prompt asking for a specific #

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Yea, attending the university and this was part of the assignment. Forgot to mention the IDE has like an integrated input where it asks for the international number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to output 800 you can use : area_Code % 1000
and to output the 1 you can use : area_Code / 1000

```
System.out.println(area_Code / 1000 + "(" + area_Code % 1000 + ") ");
```

Comment: Will do, more along the lines of my skill-set. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear *why* you are parsing the input into a `long`, I would stick with `String` for input (and if you want to be safe, perhaps remove all non-digits and validate that it is actually eleven characters long). Something like,

```
String phoneNumber = scnr.nextLine().replaceAll("\\D+", "");
if (phoneNumber.length() == 11) {
    System.out.printf("+1 (%s) %s-%s%n", phoneNumber.substring(1, 4), 
            phoneNumber.substring(4, 7), phoneNumber.substring(7));
}
```

With your sample input I get (as requested)

```
+1 (800) 555-1212
```

Alternatively,

```
int lineNumber = (int) (phoneNumber % 10000);
int areaCode = (int) (phoneNumber / 10000 / 1000) - 1000;
int coCode = (int) (phoneNumber / 10000) - (areaCode * 1000) - 1000000;
System.out.printf("+1 (%d) %d-%d%n", areaCode, coCode, lineNumber);
```

or

```
System.out.print("+1 (");
System.out.print(areaCode);
System.out.print(") ");
System.out.print(coCode);
System.out.print("-");
System.out.println(lineNumber);
```

Comment: I haven’t learned any of these formatting options, I will try and comment back.

Comment: @ErickGuerrero I recommend you use this solution. Even if you are not familiarized with `printf` method, at the very least you should familiarize yourself with the `String` class and its methods. When you look at both of the snippets provided by Elliott Frisch, you can see that the `substring` operations are more readable than messing with modulus. That is, if using `String` over `long` for the input is an option.

Answer (score 1):

```
int first = (int) (phoneNumber / 10000000);
int second = (int) (phoneNumber % 10000000) / 10000;
int third = (int) (phoneNumber % 10000);
System.out.printf("(%d) %d-%d%n", first, second, third);
```

The first line gets the first 3 digits.

The second line get the remainder but after dividing by 10000 it gets only the 3 middle digits.

The third line gets you the 4 remainder digits.